# Can't checkout sources using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

There is a project repository
http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/pokersource/trunk/poker-eval/
but I can't checkout it with my TortoiseSVN. 
The error is

> Repository moved permanently to '/viewcvs/pokersource/trunk/poker-eval/';

What's wrong with it? Could anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you provided is only intended for human interaction with a webbrowser, not for SVN client tools. The SVN repository URL is http://svn.gna.org/svn/pokersource/trunk (see gna.org project page)!

Answer (score 1):

The link you are pointing to (http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/pokersource/trunk/poker-eval/) does not seem to be a repository URL at all. It seems to be a ViewCVS URL.

ViewCVS is a server that allows you to browse a repository and its history, but does not actually necessarily function like an SVN server, for TortoiseSVN to be able to communicate with.

Comment: Does that means there is no way to checkout the project?

Comment: Good catch - you can still checkout the project, but you'll need the SVN project url - this is just an alternative way to view the existing repositories.

Answer (score 0):

What steps are you taking to perform the checkout?  Do you know who setup the repository initially?

A lot of svn clients will give this error if the repository url is incorrectly specified (as indicated by this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/80724/how-to-fix-repository-moved-permanently-to-using-visualsvn-subversion)).

Comment: I can see the project structure in browser by this link http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/pokersource/trunk/poker-eval/ . I do SVN Checkout with Tortoise SVN and post this url to the "Repository URL" and clik "Ok"

Comment: Are you attempting to checkout to an empty folder (e.g. no existing children folders/files under the destination target)?

Comment: Yes. The destination folder is absolutely empty